# How to automatically lock Dropbox files to prevent multiple users from working simultaneously?

Tags: dropbox, blocking, lock

We use Dropbox to sync files we're working on between multiple computers. Is there a way to automatically lock a synced file on other computers when one user opens it for editing, so it's impossible for multiple users to edit a file simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a distributed version control system. It also sounds like your users may not be tech savvy enough to use one. If you are on Windows, you might be able to get away with using something like Git+[TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/). However, only you know whether your users and the files they work on, would be able to handle merging with conflicts and performing the necessary pull then push operations from their local repository to the Dropbox "master".

One caveat is that if your design files are very large and in a binary format, DVCS is probably not the way to go. It sounds like files might be large due to your comment about losing gigabytes of data.

You will get a better answer if you add some more details. For example, what CAD program are you using? What are the typical file sizes and formats? How often are users trying to edit the same file?